# How do I add elements to an ExtJS component tpl so that I can refer to them in a listeners config

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I can add a listener to the 'el' element of a component like this:

```
Ext.widget('component',{
    listeners: {
        click: {
            element: 'el', //bind to the underlying el property on the component
            fn: function(){ console.log('you clicked the el'); }
        }
    }
}
```

But I want to add more elements to this component's tpl and listen for clicks on them. In place of `'el'` in the example above, I want to use a custom element `'awesomelink'`. How do I reference elements in the tpl from the listeners config?

Here's an unfinished example:

```
Ext.widget('component',{
    tpl : '<div>{content}<a class="awesomelink">click this awesome link</a></div>',
    data:{content:'something'},
    listeners: {
        click: {
            element: 'awesomelink', // this doesn't mean anything 
            fn: function(){ console.log('you clicked the awesomelink'); }
        }
    }
}
```

I assume I need an `awesomelink` property on the component - but how would that relate to the tpl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event delegation:

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: function(c) {
        c.getEl().on('click', function(e, t) {
            console.log(t);
        }, null, {delegate: '.awesomelink'});
    }
}
```

Comment: Evan, I can't find anything about this in the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-on). Also, it does not work in my [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2qv).

Comment: Thanks, I've found it in the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-on). However, you need to pass an object `{delegate: '.awesomelink'}` to get it work. Cool feature, though!

Comment: Wow. Having a shocker tonight...!

Comment: OK - so delegate is the cleanest solution... Fair enough. I'll confirm when I can. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `element` config expects the name of a **property** on the component which contains a reference to a DOM element, where you want to add your listener (refer to the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-listeners)).

That's why you can use "el", since all components have this property, but not "awesomelink" (unless you add that property yourself).

However, the click event on the component's underlying element will also fire if you click on child nodes of that element, so you could just check if the target element is your link in the listener:

```
listeners: {
    click: {
        element: 'el',
        fn: function(e, t) {
            if (Ext.get(t).hasCls('awesomelink')) {
                console.log('you clicked the awesomelink');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah this what I have currently @matt but it's a bit fugly. I read the docs re: the `'el'` but couldn't find a solution there

Comment: Your explanation makes perfect sense, thx @matt. any chance you have an e.g. of adding `awesomelink` (or whatever) as a property? No biggy.

Comment: You could use an `afterrender` listener and add something like: `this.awesomelink = this.el.down('.awesomelink');`.